# page navigation with routing

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have this code in my Global.asax file:

```
 Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoute(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub
    'about.aspx
    Sub RegisterRoute(ByVal _routes As RouteCollection)
        With _routes
            .MapPageRoute("homepage", "Home", "~/default.aspx")
            .MapPageRoute("aboutpage", "About", "~/about.aspx")
            .MapPageRoute("producs", "Products", "~/products/Default.aspx")
            .MapPageRoute("adFin", "Products/{name}", "~/products/Default.aspx")
            .MapPageRoute("news", "News", "~/news.aspx")
            .MapPageRoute("contact", "Contact", "~/contact.aspx")

        End With
    End Sub
```

Anytime I navigate to Product/Myproductname it work fine but if i navigate back to home the url still reads Product/Home instead of Home

Answer (score 0):

My thought is you are probably generating your link via the ActionLink method-- which uses the current Controller, which is "Product". You probably want to create the link manually without the HtmlHelper--- just link to Home